# Display attribute on shop page after the title

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic, actions

I am using the following code for displaying a custom attribute on the Woocommerce shop page. But for some reason, the year is displayed above the product image instead of after the product title (In between the product title and the price).

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'YearOfMake', 10);

function YearOfMake()
{
    global $product;

    $abv = $product->get_attribute('year-made');
    if (empty($abv))
        return;
    echo __($abv, 'woocommerce');
}
```

Link: https://groovygarbs.com/cars/

Answer (score 1):

```
add_filter( 'the_title', 'YearOfMake', 10, 2 );
function YearOfMake( $title, $post_id ) 
{

    if ( get_post_type( $post_id ) != 'product' && ! is_archive() )
        return $title;

    if ( ! ( is_shop() || is_product_category() || is_product_tag() ) )
        return $title;
    /*
        global $product;
        $attribute  = 'year-made';
        $abv        = $product->get_attribute($attribute);
        if(!empty($abv))
        {
            $title .= '<br /><p>' . $abv . '</p>';
        }
    */
    $terms  = wp_get_post_terms( $post_id, 'product_tag' );
    $term   = reset( $terms );
    if ( !empty( $term->name ))
    {
        $title .= '<br /><p>' . strtoupper( $term->name ) . '</p>';
    }
    return $title;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'YearOfMake', 15);
function YearOfMake()
{
    global $product;
    $attribute  = 'year-made';
    $abv        = $product->get_attribute($attribute);
    if(!empty($abv))
    {
        echo '<p>' . $abv . '</p>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, it didn't work. :(

Comment: Please double check this **year-made** attribute spelling and also check its present or not

Comment: Hi, the attribute becomes visible and I can see the year with my code. But it is not getting displayed after the product title (In between the product title and the price). The result is the same with the code you have given too. Please see the link: https://groovygarbs.com/cars/

Comment: I saw your link, its product tag not attribute. I posted new answer for that